# Creating an OpenVas-based scanner using Python and Docker technology

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, openvas

I have project: "Network device scanning system with detection of potential threats and email reporting".
I need to use python and Openvas scanner to write a code for scanning given addresses for example.
The finished solution should be encapsulated into a virtualisation container (e.g. Docker).

## I was trying to use `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN pip install python-gvm

RUN python -c "import gvm; print('SUCCESS')"

COPY main.py /app/main.py

CMD ["python", "/app/main.py"]
```

And my simple python code is:

```
from gvm.connections import UnixSocketConnection  # Import UnixSocketConnection

def scan_with_openvas():
    # Initialize UnixSocketConnection with the path to the OpenVAS UNIX socket
    connection = UnixSocketConnection(path="/var/run/openvas/gvmd.sock")

    # Initialize Gmp object with the UnixSocketConnection
    with Gmp(connection=connection) as gmp:
        # The rest of the code remains the same
        gmp.authenticate()
        targets = gmp.get_targets()
        for target in targets:
            print(target["name"])
        new_target = gmp.create_target("TARGET_IP", name="My Target")
        config = gmp.create_scan_config(name="Full and Fast", scanner="1")
        scan = gmp.create_scan(target=new_target, config=config)
        while not scan["status"] == "Done":
            scan = gmp.get_scan(scan_id=scan["@id"])
        results = gmp.get_results(scan_id=scan["@id"])
        print("\n")
        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scan_with_openvas()
```

However, the result showed:

**gvm.errors.GvmError: Socket /var/run/openvas/gvmd.sock does not exist**

I am asking for a lot of help with the idea of solving this problem. Alternative ways of solving it are also accepted.

Comment: A container runs in an isolated environment, and it can't normally see Unix sockets or other files on the host system.

Comment: so how can I solve this problem?